# Create MappedRwLockWriteGuard from a reference in if/else in Rust

Tags: rust, locking, mutex, borrow-checker, rwlock

I am trying to use `parking_lot` to write a block of code where I am using the property of a `RwLock` whenever I don't already have a reference to it:

```rust
let property = if i_already_have_the_reference {
  simple_mut_reference_to_property
} else {
  my_lock.write().map(|v| v.property)
};
```

However, this doesn't work since the first branch is a simple `&mut MyReference` type, and the second branch is a `MappedRwLockWriteGuard`.

If I dereference `MappedRwLockWriteGuard` with `&mut`, the compiler will drop the temporary at the end of the else branch.

So, the only solution I can think of is to create a dummy `MappedRwLockWriteGuard` from `simple_mut_reference_to_property`, which doesn't actually unlock a lock on the drop.

What is your suggestion to fix this problem?

If impossible, is there an API that allows manual lock/unlocking of the C-way?

P.S: the reason I use `parking_lot` instead of `std::sync` is that I thought I can fix the issue with `.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful pattern in cases like that is to have a variable that is sometimes initialized and sometimes not. You can hold the lock in that variable:

```rust
let mut write_guard;
let property = if i_already_have_the_reference {
    simple_mut_reference_to_property
} else {
    write_guard = my_lock.write();
    &mut write_guard.property
};
```